# Lightning design system for an external application

Tags: integration, slds

I am implement an external application that should be embedded into the Visualforce page. The application is based on the HTML and CSS. For the front-end I've choosen a bootstrap.

It all works just fine but now after a brand new [Saleasforce Lightning Design System](http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com) (SLDS) was presented I am thinking about to move my front-end to the SLDS. Since there is no javascript engine yet that support SLDS, I need to implement some functionallity by myself using some third party framework (no idea at the moment, maybe jQuery?).

Additionally my application should be 'Lightning Ready'. That means that all elements on the page and general look and feel of the app should match the style guide of the lightning design.

What is the best practice integrating SLDS into the application? Is jQuery a right choice for that? Or should I just adapt existing bootstrap css classes for the new design?

Answer (score 4):

There is no particular recommendation on which JavaScript technology to use. JQuery is an option but you could also use Angular or React. The best practice depends on which technology you feel most comfortable with.
Adapting existing Bootstrap CSS for the new design or a theme would be an alternative. It depends on the complexity of your application.